# How can one put matches extracted from strings existing in an array and pass them into variables that already exist in an array--in Perl?

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, loops

Just like the title laboriously explains, I'm looking for a way to pass matches from individual elements in an existing array into uninitialized variables stored in an existing array, *i.e.* consider the following:

```
my $data1;
my $data2;
my $data3;

my @data_pod(
    $data1,
    $data2,
    $data3
);

my @array ( "a1", "b1", "c1" );

foreach (@array)
{
    #GET RID OF THE 1'S BY A PATTERN MATCH
    #STORE THE RESULT IN APPROPRIATE ELEMENT OF date_pod
}
```

The end result should make this

```
foreach (@data_pod)
{
    print "$_\r\n";
}
```

produce this

```
a
b
c
```

Just assume that the match only matches singleton lowercase alphabetic characters. Of course, this is a metaphor to get at what I'm really after. I'm thinking along the lines of something akin to the following:

```
foreach my $cat (@quarters)
{
    push @slim_quarters, $cat =~ /[A-Z][a-z]*, [A-Z][a-z]* \d*/g;
}
```

---

*n.b.* - I'm new to Perl. I'm a baby.

---

```
use Date::Calc qw( Today Date_to_Days Now );

# MIGHT BE ABLE TO USE THIS / MODIFY
# Lower Limit
my $year1    =;
my $month1   = 7;
my $day1     = $slim_quarters[0];
my $hour1    = 00;
my $min1     = 00;
my $minlower = ($hour1 * 60) + $min1;

# Upper Limit
my $year2    = 2001;
my $month2   = 7;
my $day2     = 6;
my $hour2    = 20;
my $min2     = 59;
my $minupper = ($hour2 * 60) + $min2;

# Current System Time
my $now = localtime();
print $now, "\n";

# Get current time from module
($year, $month, $day) = Today();
($hour, $min,) = Now();
my $minnow = ($hour * 60) + $min;
print "It is now $hour:$min or $minnow minutes since midnight\n";

$lower = Date_to_Days($year1, $month1, $day1);
$upper = Date_to_Days($year2, $month2, $day2);
$date  = Date_to_Days($year,  $month,  $day);
print "$lower=lower\t$upper=upper\t$date=date\n";

if (($date >= $lower) && ($date <= $upper)) {
  if (($date != $lower) && ($date != $upper)) {
    print "Not on a start and stop day\n";
  }
  elsif (($date == $lower) && ($date == $upper)) {
    print "same start and stop date\n";
    if (($minnow >= $minlower) && ($minnow < $minupper)) {
      print "match on dates and mins within range\n";
    }
    else {
      print "BUT not within minute range\n";
      exit();
    }
  }
  elsif (($date == $lower) && ($minnow < $minlower)) {
    print "before start time\n";
    exit();
  }
  elsif (($date == $upper) && ($minnow > $minupper)) {
    print "after end time\n";
    exit();
  }
  print "GOOD\n";
}
else {
  print "out of range\n";
}
```

Comment: this will never work, because the elements in `@data_pod` are _copies_ of `$data1` etc, not references to them.

Comment: All I know--so far--about hashes is what's provided here: http://qntm.org/files/perl/perl.html

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What *exactly* are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Exactly that stuff up there in the OP. It would just be processing different data.

Comment: @user3269763 That's not the problem you're trying to solve. That's just the design you envisioned as the means of solving it.  Back up a couple steps and give us a bigger picture.

Comment: I don't see what the code you have shown (and I have tidied up!) has to do with your original question. But perhaps that's what you were going to explain. Note that is doesn't compile because of `my $year1 =;`

Comment: The `@slim_quarters` is a trimmed version of a tag I scraped from a calendar HTML file. I want to trim it even more to get rid of the first bits of data. The data in `@slim_quarters` is of the following form: `Monday, June 13` I want to get rid of the `Monday, ` part and somehow store/parse the `June 13` part into a date object. From here, I'd like to then used the captured dates--there is a particular order that is respected--and use them as begin and end points to determine if a user-specified date falls between them.

Comment: What do you need that `use Date::Parse; strptime('Monday, June 13');` doesn't do? (It returns the list `(undef, undef, undef, 13, 5, undef, undef)`). But this still seems like two separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). I'll attempt to answer the question you should have asked instead of the question you actually asked.

---

Based on your comments, the crux of your problem seems to be parsing and comparing dates. [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html), a core module since Perl 5.10, can handle both of these tasks:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $format = '%A, %B %d';

# Parse
my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime('Monday, June 13', $format);
my $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime('Friday, June 17', $format);

# Compare
say 't1 > t2' if $t1 > $t2;
say 't2 > t1' if $t2 > $t1;

# Print
say $_->strftime('%B %d') for $t1, $t2;
```

#### Output:

```
t2 > t1
June 13
June 17
```

Comment: how would one do this if there is a preexisting `$year` value? I mean how would `my $format = '%A, %B %d';` change? I mean, because I want to be able to do something like this: `my $t0 = Time::Piece->strptime($date1 . $year, $format);` Is this allowable? That is, is `$date1 . $year` allowable?

Comment: Would it just be `%Y`?

Comment: The format codes are documented in the [manpage for FreeBSD's `strftime`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/strftime/). The format for the four-digit year is `%Y`.

Comment: What about `$date . ($year + 1)`?

Comment: If `$date` is `Monday, June 13` and `$year` is `2000`, then `$date . ($year + 1)` evaluates to `Monday, June 132001` (note that the day and year are mashed together because you didn't include any spaces when you concatenated the two strings). The `strptime` format for this would be `%A, %B %d%Y`. Please read the documentation I linked to in my previous comment for more details.

Comment: no I mean can that expression--with a space between the day and year values--be put in place of your 'Friday, June 17' if I adjust `$format` accordingly? Like, can `$date . " " . ($year + 1)` be used in `strptime` like this? Essentially, is this possible: `my $t0 = Time::Piece->strptime($date . " " . ($year + 1), $format);`

Comment: You could always try it to find out :) But yes, it is possible. Also note that Time::Piece allows you to do date math, e.g. `my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date, $format); my $next_year = $t->add_years(1);`

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you may have started with the wrong design, but this will work for you. If you tell us more about the steps you took to conclude that this is what you want then I am sure we can help.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @data_pod = \my ($data1, $data2, $data3);

my @array = qw( a1 b1 c1 );

for my $i (0 .. $#array) {
  ${ $data_pod[$i] } = $array[$i] =~ s/1//r;
}

say for $data1, $data2, $data3;
```

**output**

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: Wait is `date->yy` how you access the `%y` value? I mean, can I do `date->yy == "13"` in a condition?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, yeah?